# How can using the existing fields, the value of another field achieved?

Tags: matlab, find

I have a Table as follows:

```
    cl   c2   c3 .....
 r1  x    A   4
 r2  y    B   5
 r3  z    C   2
 .
 .
 .
```

r(1,2,3) are label of rows and c(1,2,3) are label of columns. I have a field of c1,c2 and I want c3. For example I have y and B, so I want achieve to '5';
I read  'Find , sub2ind' Functions but I do not know how can I use them For this case.

Comment: How does `y` and `B` give you `5`?

Comment: just one row exist that c1=y and c2=B  (itis unique). I want search in table and find this row and extract field of c3 (=5).

Comment: Do I need to write a function for the job and MATLAB has not function for this job ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple logical indexing to accomplish this. You want the third column when the value of the first column is `'y'` and the value of the second column is `'B'`

```
t = table({'x'; 'y'; 'z'}, {'A'; 'B'; 'C'}, [4; 5; 2], 'VariableNames', {'c1', 'c2', 'c3'});

value = t.c3(ismember(t.c1, 'y') & ismember(t.c2, 'B'))
%   5
```